# How to get a single value out of two value with same name in join table result?

Tags: php, mysql

I run the following query and get the result :

[image: The print view]

Now if I am running the following then I am getting user_id as 0.

```
<?php 
        session_start();
        require_once('connectvars.php');
        $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

        $result = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM `user_question`join question WHERE user_question.qid = question.qid and user_question.user_id = $user_id")
        or die("Error in fetching the value.");

        while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo 'user id : ';
            echo $row['user_id'];
            echo "<br>";
            echo 'qid: ';
            echo $row['qid'];
            echo "<br>";
            echo 'answer_key: ';
            echo $row['answer_key'];
                    echo "<br>";

        }


     ?>
```

How can I get user_id : 4 ?

Comment: Simple answer to your question is select only needed columns donot select all (*) columns ,you have user_id name for 2 columns so the last one is returned or either give a unique alias to your user_id column whom you want to display

Comment: Unique alias to user_id column? How can I do it ?

Comment: Like `select *,user_question.user_id AS ques_user_id` and then in php you can have this id `echo $row['ques_user_id'];`

Comment: Jazak Allah Khairan bro..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT user_question.user_id,user_question.qid,user_question.answer_key FROM `user_question`join question WHERE user_question.qid = question.qid and user_question.user_id = $user_id")
```

Now echo $row['user_id']...